# How to save an audio file

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor

I have a video where I deleted the animation part and I only have the sound.

When I try to save the file it saves as `.blend`, how can I save it as an mp3 file. I have already set the start up file to save as mp3.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. You export filetypes, you cant save them directly. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Then only thing you "save" with blender is `.blend` files. For any other format you'll have to render or export. I'm not sure if you can directly render an mp3 from blender, but you can render a video file with mp3 audio and no video codec..

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I have the export option but it doesn't list mp3 files

Comment: @gandalf3 could you please tell me how to do it. This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *Properties > Output*, set something like this:

[image]

It's not ideal, but maybe it'll work for you..

Answer (score 19):

**Properties-->Render-->Audio** and select the format in the windows (mp3 / flac ...) make sure properties-->Render-->post processing--> sequencer" is enable (if sequencer is the audio input)
[image: Properties-->Render-->Audio]

Comment: This is the correct way to export audio. Make sure the format matches your input, in my case it was S32, otherwise the audio will be garbled. This is found in the save settings after pressing 'Audio'.

Comment: Then click "mixdown"

Comment: This is the way I used.

Comment: in blender 2.8?

Answer (score 6):

Audio can be exported to lossless .flac audiofile by pressing render/audio button.

[image]

Comment: As well as other codecs / containers including "ogg" "mp3"

Answer (score 1):

Output format to .mp4 then use an online converter to change it to .mp3. I use http://media.io/

Comment: If attempting to get .mp3 you could choose it in Blender as output codec as well, without any converting.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
In Blender 2.93, the Render Audio command is located in the **Top Menu\Render\Render Audio**.